# Exclude Compiled Source From Custom Jar with Gradle

Tags: gradle, jar, build.gradle

I'm trying to build a JAR from a specific package of classes so I want to exclude all the other packages from this JAR. This is what I have...

```
task receiverJar(type: Jar) {
  baseName = "receivers"
  from sourceSets.main.output
  include 'com/foo/receivers/**'
  exclude 'com/foo/cli/**'
  exclude 'com/foo/tdl/**'
  with jar
}
```

When I execute `gradle receiverJar` I still get all the other packages and classes in my JAR file.

Comment: Well, the problem is that my sourceSet needs to be custom then, I would assume. I have other builds that require a specific sourceSet. Can I create a sourceSet custom for a specific task?

Comment: No, because if I exclude my current sourceSet, other tasks won't work. So can you tell me how to include a custom sourceSet into my receverJar task?

Comment: Well, so here's the real deal. I need to compile everything, but only include a subset of the compiled classes into a JAR file. So a custom sourceSet (which I figured out) fails to compile because of dependencies on other classes. So to my original question, I want to build a JAR but exclude some packages from the JAR file.

Comment: Are you sure you're examining the correct jar? Using your (correct) notation, my custom jar correctly included/excluded the specified classes.

Comment: Also the `with jar` should not be needed

Comment: guess I'm out of my depths here, I apologize.

Comment: Oh btw, if you create a custom sourceset, can you have your receiverJar task dependsOn jar task, that way all sourcesets are compiled, but receivers.jar contains only your custom sourceSet.

Comment: The issue was the `with jar`. I removed that and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
task receiverJar(type: Jar) {
    enabled = true
    baseName this.name + '-receivers'
    from sourceSets.main.output
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Version': project.version
    }
    include 'com/foo/tdl/**'
    exclude 'com/foo/cdl/**'
}
```